# Error while adding glassfish tools with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, glassfish

I am trying to add Glassfish tools using Download additional server adaptors in Eclipse Kepler but getting error.

Setup details are:
Eclipse kepler 64 bit 
Windows 7 64 bit

The error I am getting is--

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: GlassFish Tools 6.4.0.201403011416 (oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish.feature.group 6.4.0.201403011416)
  Missing requirement: GlassFish Tools 6.4.0.201403011416 (oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish 6.4.0.201403011416) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.jst.server.generic.core [1.0.800,1.1.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: GlassFish Tools 6.4.0.201403011416 (oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish.feature.group 6.4.0.201403011416)
    To: oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish.ui [6.4.0.201403011416]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: GlassFish Tools UI 6.4.0.201403011416 (oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish.ui 6.4.0.201403011416)
    To: bundle oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish [6.4.0,6.5.0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added below component to Eclipse:

1. JST server adaptors
2. JST server adaptors Extentions
3. JST server UI

By going to Help-> Install New softwares in Eclipse
Select work with as 
Kepler - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler

The required components are available under category
Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development

Comment: In addition I also had to install the following packages from the same source: JSF Tools, WST Server Adapters (not sure about this but installed anyway), Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools and Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools.